# How to count only specific word in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

For example i have a data like this

```
Ambassador Classic Nova Diesel
Audi A3 35 TDI Attraction
Audi A3 35 TDI Premium
Ford Figo Diesel EXI
Ford Figo Diesel EXI
Honda Accord 2.4 A/T
Honda Accord 2.4 A/T
Honda WRV i-VTEC VX
Honda WRV i-VTEC VX
Hyundai Accent CRDi
Hyundai Accent CRDi
Mini Cooper Countryman D High
Mini Cooper S
Mini Cooper S Carbon Edition
```

and i only want to count only the brand of the car, how do i do it?

Comment: You'll need a list of Car Brands seperately. Excel won't be able to magically know car brands =)

Comment: First I would use left() to get the first word of each entry and then remove duplicates  - assuming that manufacturer is always first.

Comment: Are you using sheets or excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with two simple steps in Microsoft Excel:

1. Select `Data` -> `Text to Columns` and then `Delimited` -> `Tab`. This will assign the brand and the model details to separate cells.
2. Mark the data and select `Insert` -> `Pivot Table`. Select the brand column and set the value to `Count`. This should solve your problem.